# GGplot add "word" to y axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample data

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + geom_boxplot()
```

My attempt

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + geom_boxplot() + ylab(len == 10, "ten")
```

Here the goal is to replace '10' on the y-axis with "ten"

Comment: You mean the value tick label at 10 with ten or just the ylab?

Comment: the value of the tick label should be 10 not the ylab thank you

Comment: Try with `+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(10,20,30), label=c("Ten",20,30))`

Comment: Thank you I select your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace on the y-axis only the value 10 with "Ten", you can use this solution:

```
library(databases)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) + geom_boxplot() +
       scale_y_continuous(label=function(x) ifelse(x==10,"Ten",x))
```

[image]